# How to get Javascript function's source code from specific site using firebug?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

With firebug I found that clicking on the link calls javascript function

```
<a href="#" onclick="viewHide(this);return false;">
```

But I couldn't find it's implementation in page source.
Is it possible to get it?

The site is in hebrew, but I don't think it's problem :[link text](http://www.nrg.co.il/online/1/ART1/937/362.html?hp=1&loc=1&tmp=781) to trigger for this function click on any comments title that follow the article.

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Comment: Do I see inverted text in the screenshot?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just write in console:

```
viewHide.toString()
```

You will get a source code of function as a text.

Answer (score 4):

You can also put **ViewHide** under the Name column of the watch panel on the Script tab.  When you press enter or click out after putting in the name, it should evaluate it and put the code in the Value column.

Answer (score 0):

Just write in console:

```
console.log(viewHide)
```

Then *double-click the output* will jump to the source file of the function definition.